# Token indices sequence length error with langchain

Tags: huggingface, py-langchain

Getting the following error when running load_qa_chain with map_reduce:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (2108 > 1024
```

The code:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

model="ehartford/WizardLM-7B-Uncensored"
text_gen_pipeline = pipeline(
    model = model, 
    model_kwargs= {
        "device_map": "auto", 
        "load_in_8bit": True, 
        # default-explain-code settings from https://platform.openai.com/examples
        "temperature": 0,
        "top_p": 1.0,
    },
    max_new_tokens=2500)
    
from langchain import HuggingFacePipeline
llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=text_gen_pipeline)

from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap = 50)
# data is loaded with GitLoader
chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS

vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)

query = "How do you use the HamburgerMenu component?"
docs = vectorstore.similarity_search(query)

from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")

result = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this error eventually?